# Vala Gstreamer BusFunc

Tags: gstreamer, vala

**Im trying to rewrite this piece of code to Vala:**

[gstreamer example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-level.html)

I got stuck at this line:

```
 watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, message_handler, NULL);
```

My vala equivalent:

```
    var watch_id = bus.add_watch (Priority.DEFAULT, message_handler);
```

**I haven't got a clue how to format the BusFunc and it's supposed arguments**

[BusFunc](https://valadoc.org/gstreamer-1.0/Gst.BusFunc.html)

Complete code so far:

```
using Gst;

bool Gst.BusFunc message_handler ()
{
  return false;
}

void main (string[] args) {
// Initializing GStreamer
Gst.init (ref args);

var caps = Caps.from_string("audio/x-raw,channels=2");

// Creating pipeline and elements
var pipeline = new Pipeline ("my_pipeline");
var bin = new Bin ("my_bin");
var bus = new Bus ();

var src = ElementFactory.make ("autoaudiosrc", "my_src");
var sink = ElementFactory.make ("autoaudiosink", "my_sink");

var convert = ElementFactory.make ("audioconvert", "my_convert");
var level = ElementFactory.make ("level", "my_level");
var fakesink = ElementFactory.make ("fakesink", "my_fakesink");

// Adding elements to pipeline
//pipeline.add_many (src, sink);

bin.add_many (pipeline, src, convert, level, fakesink);

src.link(convert);
convert.link_filtered (level, caps);
level.link(fakesink);

level.set ("post-messages", true);
fakesink.set ("sync", true);

bus = pipeline.get_bus ();

var watch_id = bus.add_watch (Priority.DEFAULT, message_handler);

// Linking source to sink
src.link (sink);


// Set pipeline state to PLAYING
pipeline.set_state (State.PLAYING);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. A delegate identifies the function signature: its parameter types and return type. The [BusFunc](https://valadoc.org/gstreamer-1.0/Gst.BusFunc.html) type has the signature: `public delegate bool BusFunc (Bus bus, Message message)` so your handler will be something like:

```cs
bool message_handler (Bus my_bus, Message my_message)
{
  print (@"Message type: $(my_message.type.get_name ())\n");
  return true;
}
```

It returns `true` in this example to keep the handler.

This example is not tested, but should give you the right idea to move forward.